# How to use default value in wicket image

Tags: java, wicket

I want to show logo of team, but team or their logo can be null. When there is null I want to use some default image in my context path. Is there some options how to use default value when value from default object of my component is null ?

```
            listItem.add(new Label("team.name"));
            listItem.add(new ExternalImage("team.logo"));
```

this is generated img:

```
<img src="null">
```

I tried something like this but I am not sure it this is OK:

```
    add(new ExternalImage("team.logo") {

        @Override
        protected void buildSrcAttribute(ComponentTag tag, IModel<?> srcModel) {

            String src = String.valueOf(srcModel.getObject());
            if (src != null && !src.equals("null")) {
                super.buildSrcAttribute(tag, srcModel);
            } else {
                final String rewritten = UrlUtils.rewriteToContextRelative("/img/defaultLogo.png",
                        RequestCycle.get());
                tag.put("src", rewritten);
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is good!

As you probably know Wicket uses `IModel` as a provider for the Component's data. In your case you use a CompoundPropertyModel on a parent Component that tries to load the external image's src from the `team.logo` property. You can achieve the same more explicitly by using a PropertyModel:

```
 add(new ExternalImage("team.logo", new PropertyModel("team.logo")));
```

To implement it in the Wicket-way you could use a wrapping model - a model that will delegate to another model and fallback to a default value if the delegate returns an "empty" value.

```
 add(new ExternalImage("team.logo", new ModelWithDefault(new PropertyModel("team.logo"), () -> {...}))); // replace '...' with the logic to calculate the default.
```

`ModelWithDefault` is not coming with Wicket. It is something you should implement yourself.

Comment: Can you not just use `new PropertyModel("team.logo").orElse(defaultLogo)` when using Wicket 8+?

Comment: Really good point, @magicmn! I've forgotten about it!